# issue in passing timestamp as argument in Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, sh

I want to pass time-stamp in the "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format using shell Script,
I mean from shell script I will call my jar file and pass the parameters as argument,
so I am doing like as -

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`
spark-submit --jars ./mylibs/log4j-1.2.17.jar --class com.mycom.test.jobtest.agg myApp-.0.1.jar $DATE
```

if I take echo of DATE it will give the proper date as expected format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" but while parsing in java it is considering space and taking only date part, and giving error as under-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-08"
```

Please suggest best way to pass time-stamp as argument,

Answer (score 5):

Pass it in double quotes: `"$DATE"`

Comment: @user392589 I'm glad. So please consider marking the answer as accepted (that's the equivalent of "Thanks, it works" on StackOverflow).